# Self Initializing Cellular Automata

Tags: cellular-automata

What is the largest cellular automata one can generate given the conditions:

-n x m rectangular grid

-Basic Conway Rules

-Grid is not continuous (meaning edge behavior is not wrapped)

-perfectly/near perfectly reproduces its initialization pattern (therefore recursive).

Comment: homework or what?

Comment: no just a question

Comment: still waiting on an answer here.

Comment: Your question has received very little attention here. I think the right forum for this question will be [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). Try posting there. thanks

Comment: Any kind of still life or oscillator pattern... Make some search on the subject you will find a lot!

Comment: You need reproductioni isn't it? Then look at autorepoductive pattern it has been a long field of research in the past. There exists a lot of patterns.